# Jquery, check if multilevel array already has this in it or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to push "arrayOne" into a multilevel array(arrayTwo). First I want to make sure it doesn't exist already so there is no duplicates. here is my code:

```
var arrayOne = ["3", "total_2"];
var arrayTwo = [["1", "total_2"], ["2", "total_4"], ["2", "total_6"], ["2", "total_11"]];

if (arrayTwo has arrayOne) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    arrayTwo.push(arrayOne);   
}
```

Im thinking im just confused on the syntax of this part:

```
if (arrayTwo has arrayOne) {
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/odksh2th/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in function to check for the existence of an array contents in another array so you just have to build one:

```
function arrayCompare(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
         return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// see if the contents of one array is in another array as a sub-array
function lookForArray(source, content) {
    var subArray;
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (arrayCompare(source[i], content)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
var arrayOne = ["3", "total_2"];
var arrayTwo = [["1", "total_2"], ["2", "total_4"], ["2", "total_6"], ["2", "total_11"]];

if (!lookForArray(arrayTwo, arrayOne)) {
    // arrayOne not found in arrayTwo
}
```

Working snippet:

```js
function arrayCompare(arr1, arr2) {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
         return false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// see if the contents of one array is in another array as a sub-array
function lookForArray(source, content) {
    var subArray;
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (arrayCompare(source[i], content)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var arraySource = [["1", "total_2"], ["2", "total_4"], ["2", "total_6"], ["2", "total_11"]];
var arrayOne = ["3", "total_2"];
var arrayTwo = ["2", "total_4"];

if (!lookForArray(arraySource, arrayOne)) {
    // arrayOne not found in arrayTwo
    document.write("arrayOne not found in arraySource<br>");
}

if (lookForArray(arraySource, arrayTwo)) {
    document.write("arrayTwo found in arraySource");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to go into each individual array and compare elements with the array that you're about to add.

If you have for say `array1 = ["1", "total_2"]` and you try to compare it with your big array (arrayTwo). Like `array1 === arrayTwo[0]`. This will produce false as JS doesn't perform a deep duplicate check on the arrays, it only performs an instance comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.each` function to iterate through each element from arrayTwo and locate the element matching the 1st item. If its not found, just add.

```
var arrayOne = ["3", "total_2"];
var arrayTwo = [["1", "total_2"], ["2", "total_4"], ["2", "total_6"], ["2", "total_11"]];

var elementFound = false;;
$.each(arrayTwo,function(i)
{
    if(arrayTwo[i][0] === arrayOne[0][0]) // compares and matches 3 to 1,2,2,2
        elementFound = true;    
});

if(!elementFound)
    arrayTwo.push(arrayOne);
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/qk5qj33u/11/

Comment: The OP said "no duplicates" which I interpreted to mean all elements of `arrayOne` were not found in a sub-array of `arrayTwo`, not just the first item.  You are testing only the first item of each sub-array.  Your code does not work.  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s79mryew/ which illustrates how this solution fails to compare the entire sub-array.

Comment: OP is trying to insert the items from arrayOne to arrayTwo and is only checking for the duplicates in arrayTwo against arrayOne. The scope of the solution provided was only for what the OP has posted in the scenario. It could surely be extended to the compare the indexes in each function instead of checking only the zeroth index.